# Adding up all columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to add up all the columns in a DataFrame, and I'd like this sum added as a new column in the DataFrame.

I want "all" the columns available, without mentioning the first and last columns in my query.

Is this possible?

Comment: are you after `df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#random dataframe
np.random.seed(1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,5)))
df1.columns = list('ABCDE')
print df1
   A  B  C  D  E
0  5  8  9  5  0
1  0  1  7  6  9
2  2  4  5  2  4

df1['sum'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
print df1
   A  B  C  D  E  sum
0  5  8  9  5  0   27
1  0  1  7  6  9   23
2  2  4  5  2  4   17
```

Another solution for creating new columns is [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
print df1.assign(sum=df1.sum(axis=1))
   A  B  C  D  E  sum
0  5  8  9  5  0   27
1  0  1  7  6  9   23
2  2  4  5  2  4   17
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```
pd.concat([df, df.sum(axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Comment: It works, excellent. However, the new columns has been created with a header of "0" or "O". I'd prefer to see "Total" or "Sum" as the header. Is this possible?. The new column has been added to the existing df DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```